# In hadoop what's under replication and over replication mean and how does it work?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

IN map reduce concept  under replica and over replica to use.
how to balance the over replica and under replica.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are aware that by default replication factor is 3.

***Over-replicated  blocks*** are   blocks  that    exceed  their   target  replication for the file    they    belong  to. Normally,   over-replication    is  not a   problem,    and HDFS    will    automatically   delete  excess replicas. Thats how its balanced in this case.

***Under-replicated blocks*** are   blocks  that    do  not meet    their   target  replication for the file    they    belong  to.

To balance these HDFS   will    automatically   create  new replicas    of  under-replicated    blocks  until   they    meet the    target  replication.

You can get information about   the blocks  being   replicated  (or waiting to  be  replicated) using

```
hdfs    dfsadmin    -metasave. 

if you execute below command, you will get the detailed stats.

hdfs    fsck    / 
......................

Status: HEALTHY 
Total   size:   511799225   B   
Total   dirs:   10  Total   files:  22  
Total   blocks  (validated):    22  (avg.   block   size    23263601    B)  
Minimally   replicated  blocks: 22  (100.0  %)  
Over-replicated blocks: 0   (0.0    %)  
Under-replicated    blocks: 0   (0.0    %)  
Mis-replicated  blocks:     0   (0.0    %)  
Default replication factor: 3   
Average block   replication:    3.0 
Corrupt blocks:     0   
Missing replicas:       0   (0.0    %)  
Number  of  data-nodes:     4   
Number  of  racks:      1


The filesystem  under   path    '/' is  HEALTHY
```

Comment: Please convey about 'Minimally replicated blocks' as well.

Comment: replicas < minReplication ( UNDER MIN REPL'D BLOCKS )(HDFS-7537)
replicas == minReplication ( Minimally replicated blocks )
replicas < ReplicationFactor ( Under-replicated blocks )
replicas == ReplicationFactor ( Normally replicated blocks )
replicas > ReplicationFactor ( Over-replicated blocks )

if ReplicationFactor equals to minReplication, the block is counted by both Minimally and Normally blocks.